# Optimize distributions in bucketing bins in python

Tags: python, optimization, bucket, bins

I have a bucketing bin problem I'd like to solve for in Python and curious if anyone has ideas on best approaches (or existing packages). I have a population where I'd like to create 10 bins for. The population has a score and has been segmented into 5 groups.

My objective is to create bins based on the scores so that the distribution of each of the 5 groups is as granular and smooth as possible. E.g. The max distribution for each bin for Group A population < 20% AND the difference from bin 2 -> bin 3 must have a change of < +/- 10%. Same for Group B....

My thought for granularity optimization is to minimize residuals. E.g. create a uniform distribution for each of the groups (i.e. 10% for each group) and try a bunch of different cuts that would minimize the total sum of (Actual Bucket% - 10%), with the constraints set above. But don't really know how to start.

Here's an example of the dataset.

```
# intialise data of lists. 
data = {'ID':['1111', '1112', '1113', '1114',....],
        'Group':[A, A, B, B,....],
        'Score':[0.02123,0.03243,0.43543,0.12213,...]}
```

Here's what the distribution of the 5 Groups would look like with scores along he x-axis and frequency as a percent of group total along the y-axis.
[image]

Comment: are the "scores" roughly the same distribution across "groups"?  e.g. what does `data.groupby('Group')['Score'].describe()` say

Comment: No. Group A will skew towards lower scores, Group B will skew towards higher scores, and Groups C-E will be more normally distributed.

Comment: just to confirm: you're trying to pick a set of values that specify the breaks between histogram bins, these values should be optimised such that the histogram for each group (using this shared set of breaks) is as uniform as possible.  if so I'm not sure there's much you can do.  I'll try and explain in an answer, but think https://stats.stackexchange.com might be a better forum

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thanks Sam!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's much more you can do beyond:

```
p = np.arange(1, 10) / 10
q = np.quantile(data['Score'], p)
```

i.e. pick evenly spaced values `(0.1, 0.2, …, 0.9)` then use the to get quantiles of your scores.

to see why I found it difficult to do better it's helpful to go to the extremes, e.g. a single dividing cut/breakpoint.  while optimising this case there will always be a trade off between the orange group and the purple one.  putting the break point in the middle of the purple group, e.g. at 0.6, will put (almost) all the orange group into the lower group and none in the upper.  adding more cut/breakpoints doesn't help things much, the lower quantiles will always contain most of the orange group, etc.